# Sharepoint 2013 Search: Get parent web information

Tags: 2013, search, spweb

I've a search result of different webs and I Need to know to which parent web they belong. Is it possible via search to get Information from the parent object?

Thank you
Markus

Answer (score 1):

Parent SPWeb URL is not included in item search results, you only have parent Site Collection title. You need to parse item SPWeb URL from the item url.

[This blog article](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/10/how-to-display-the-site-title-and-site-url-in-search-results-aspx/) describes how to display SPWeb URL of the item in search results.